# regex to extract title

Tags: regex

I have to extract title from the text file.

Basically, I have to extract everything before either `HOST:` or `MAIL:` as `Title`:

Regex:

```
(?:(?<title>.*))(MAIL:|HOST:)
```

Sample text:

```
TITLE MSG  HOST:HOSTNAME  MAIL:a@b.com
TITLE sqlChecks [21/02/2019-22:00]:  MAIL:a@b.com HOST:HOSTNAME
```

See [current regex DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/SDOcIR/5).

Comment: Maybe `(?<title>.*?)(MAIL:.*|HOST:.*)`?

Comment: thanks !! can you convert it to answer.

Comment: Added as an answer and improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<title>.*?)(?:(?P<mail>MAIL:.*)|(?P<host>HOST:.*))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oBuQp9/2)

**Details**

- `(?<title>.*?)` - Group "title": any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?:(?P<mail>MAIL:.*)|(?P<host>HOST:.*))` - a non-capturing group matching either:

  - `(?P<mail>MAIL:.*)` - Group `mail`: `MAIL:` and the rest of the line
  - `|` - or
  - `(?P<host>HOST:.*)` - Group `host`: `HOST:` and the rest of the line

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegExp: [`(?<=TITLE\s)(?<title>.*?)(?=\s+(HOST:|MAIL:))`](https://regexr.com/48tl5)